# Автоматическая установка расширения с сайта в браузерах «Edge», «Opera» и «Safari»?

Tags: javascript, safari, opera, extension, microsoft-edge

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, есть ли возможность в браузерах "Opera", "Edge" и "Safari" создать веб-страницу, с которой пользователь, исходя из своего желания, сможет по щелчку на кнопку установить себе расширение ?

Comment: нет. это против всякой безопасности. Что бы было если бы так было. Каждый первый бы ставил майнеры и прочую штуку. Все идет через стор браузера.

Comment: Хорошо, Вас понял, благодарю за совет.

Answer (score 0):

Только через порталы приложений для браузеров.
Это сделано в цлях обезопасить пользователей от скрытых, сторонних и вредоносных установок.

Но если Вы сможете убедить пользователя включить режим разработчика в браузере (для каждого браузера своя инструкция) скачать файл приложения и вручную его установить, то все получится. Но большинство пользователей, просто не станет этого делать, потому что долго, сложно, а зачем?

Comment: Тоже верно, Вас понял.